# Issues with integer operations

Tags: php

```
function sendSms($toPhone,$message){
    $toPhone=intval(trim($toPhone));
    if(strlen($toPhone)== 8 && $toPhone{0}==9){

                    //sending sms

    }else{
        return "error";
    }

}
```

I am trying to validate mobile numbers for sending SMS. The first line trims the phone number string and then converts it to an integer. In the `if` statement, I want to make sure that the number length is 8 digits and it begins with 9. This function always goes for the `else` even if the number is correct( 8 digits and begins with 9). What could be the issue here.

Comment: did you try `if(strlen($toPhone)== 8 && $toPhone[0]==9){`

Comment: @AlecTMH yes, it does not work

Comment: @AlecTMH maybe because of `intval`

Comment: Right, you need to use regex as stated in the below post or get strlen before converting to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not regex?

```
$valid = preg_match('/^9[0-9]{7}$/', trim($phone));
```

Comment: what is the `7` for? it's an 8 digit number and it starts with 9

Comment: Because I put a 9 `9` literal followed by 7 `{7}` other numbers ranging from 0 to 9 `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from $toPhone all not digits

```
function sendSms($toPhone,$message){
    $_phone = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($toPhone); $i++)
    {
        if (is_numeric($toPhone[$i]))
           $_phone .= $toPhone[$i];
    }

    if(strlen($_phone)== 8 && $_phone[0]=='9'){
           //sending sms
    }else{
       return "error";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you converted the phone number to an integer with `$toPhone=intval(trim($toPhone));`,, you can't access the digits in the way you are trying with `$toPhone{0}`, **because you operate on a number and not on a string** any more.

See this isolated example:

```
$number = 987654321;
var_dump($number{0}); //NULL
```

However, `substr` would be capable of doing this:

```
$number = 987654321;
var_dump(substr($number, 0, 1)); //string(1) "9"
```

**Converting a whole number to integer isn't a good idea anyways**, because users might enter the number with spaces in between or signs like `+` and `/`. Better search for an already existing approach to validate phone numbers.

Take a look here, where the topic "validate mobile phone numbers" is covered in more detail: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

You convert variable to integer and apparently $toPhone[0] works on strings only.

The same function without intval() works as you wanted.

```
function sendSms($toPhone, $message)
{
    $toPhone = trim($toPhone);
    if(strlen($toPhone) == 8 && $toPhone[0] == 9){
        //sending sms
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```